# iPad app displaying iPhone screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am working on an app and it has 3 storyboards - iPad, iPhone and iPhone 4.  3 different users (myself included) have had the experience where on their iPad - the splash screen that loads is small and in the top-left corner...leaving much white space to the right and bottom.

It is as if it is loading the iPhone size splash.

I have no launch screen file selected in the general tab of the project.  I have also noticed that after restarting my iPad, it does seem to load the proper screen size.  Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: This actually only happens for me when the iPad is in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code for screen size.

```
CGRect screen_size = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
```